# SpatialLite BulkLoad and Merge

Tags: python, shapefile, spatialite

Via the U.S. Census I have downloaded all of the census group shapefiles.  These are approximately 19-20GB across 56 shapefiles.

I want to merge these to do some testing.  Clearly, shape file format is not going to work, so I am using spatialite.  I have read that spatialite journalling causes performance issues when trying to load lots of data.  Two questions:

1. Can I turn off journaling and just bulk load the data.  I'll build stats and indices later.
2. Can I merge multiple shapefiles into one table within spatialite?  I know I could use OGR and write a script to pump the data into a table one shape file at a time, but is this possible direct via spatial lite.

Disclaimer:

1. I know that this will be an ~8,200,000 row table. I am not running this in production or planning on running many queries on this.  This is a research project.
2. I could also go with a full blown PostgreSQL install and have this running, but I want to dig a bit deeper into Spatialite.

Comment: One good reason to go with PostGIS is its query planner will automatically use spatial indexes while you have to manually join to Spatialite's spatial index tables.  For a dataset this large the indexes will make a world of difference.

Comment: @HeyOverThere I total agree and would offer the same comment if someone was asking about running queries.  I would partition the data as well as 8.2 million rows is getting up there for PostGIS in a single table.  This is especially true given all the columns.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your first question is yes, and there are more options than just 'off' and 'on.' See the [journal_mode](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode) pragma.

There's also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/how-do-i-improve-the-performance-of-sqlite) on StackOverflow that has some useful info in the accepted answer.

For your second question: yes you should be able to. It wouldn't really be that much different from loading a single shape file other than you'd have to loop over each file.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up and bummed that I missed that post.  I did see references to using transactions to bulk insert.  This might be the first avenue that I explore as the data is nicely portioned into shapefiles already.